# Is it possible to print from mobile app (android, iphone) through bluetooth (BLE) printer?

Tags: flutter, mobile, printing, bluetooth

I'm creating a mobile app in flutter where I want to print A4 paper over bluetooth communication with package flutter_blue.

I'm a little confused because some printers have bluetooth option but don't have characterist for printing.

For example:
I successfully connected to the printer "HP OfficeJet 252 mobile" which has support for BLE, but cannot send data to print.

Did I just bought the wrong printer or there isn't possible to print throught bluetooth communication?

Answer (score 0):

My expectation would be that printing is not done with Bluetooth Low Energy but with Bluetooth Classic. This would be done through the [Basic Printing Profile (BPP)](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/)

Looking at the instructions for your printer, the Bluetooth only seems to be used to assist with getting the printer connected to the WiFi network. I could not find any information about sending prints directly to the printer over Bluetooth.